# explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given

Tags: php, arrays, explode

I have designed below code where i am using explode to explode below data,

```
"10.74.10.1", "10.75.10.132"
```

however i getting below error

> "explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in line.."

Can someone please suggest whats wrong in my code.

This is my full code:

```
public function pagesviewlogsAction()
    {
        // Checks authorization
        $this->acl->doCheck($this);

-- language: lang-html -->      // Validates request
        $requestObj = new PagesviewlogEventRequest();

$requestObj->userid = (Utils::validatePattern(Utils::REGEXP_SECLOGS_USERID, (($json->userid) ?? FALSE) )) ? $json->userid:NULL;
                $requestObj->clientip = array();
                //if (isset($json->clientip) && $json->clientip != '' && $json->clientip != NULL) {
                if (isset($json->clientip) && is_string($json->clientip)){
                    $tmp = explode(',', $json->clientip);                   
                    foreach ($tmp as $key => $ipValue) {
                        $requestObj->clientip[] = (Utils::validatePattern(Utils::REGEXP_SECLOGS_IP, ((trim($ipValue)) ?? FALSE) )) ? trim($ipValue):NULL;
                    }
                }

        }


        foreach (get_object_vars($requestObj) as $key => $value) {
            switch ($key) {
                case 'clientip':
                    // ...
                    break;

                default:
                   // Other cases
                    if ($value === FALSE) {
                        return new JsonModel([
                            'status' => 'FAILED',
                            'errorField' => $key,
                            'message'=> 'Parameters "' . $key . '" is missing or invalid.',
                            'data' => NULL
                        ]);
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: `"10.74.10.1", "10.75.10.132"` is not a string so you can't explode it. It's 2 elements of an array. Hence the error you get. In your situation you can just replace `$tmp` in your foreach with `$json->clientip` and it should work.

Comment: looks like clientip is an array already. Do a `var_dump($json->clientip)`

Comment: Taken from comments in answers: *"preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in"* - Umm.... where is *that* function?

Comment: This is my validatePattern function private static function _validatePattern($pattern, $value)
    {
        $validity = false;
        $validity = preg_match($pattern, $value);
        return $validity;
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function explode() will convert a string to an array using a given separator, in your case ","
Since $json->clientip is already an array, the simple(not the best) solution is to change the code to:

```
    $requestObj->clientip = array();
    if (is_array($json->clientip)) {

        foreach ($json->clientip as $key => $ipValue) {
            $requestObj->clientip[] = (Utils::validatePattern(Utils::REGEXP_SECLOGS_IP, ((trim($ipValue)) ?? FALSE) )) ? trim($ipValue):NULL;
        }
    } else {
//handle the other option here. like string or object
}
```

and it depends on the source of the $json->clientip to make sure you have the correct approach in case you don't receive an array.

Comment: Now i am getting this error : preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in..             Here,  $json->clientip =["10.74.10.1", "10.75.10.132"]

Comment: replace foreach ($json->clientip as $key => $ipValue)  with foreach ($json->clientip as $ipValue)

Comment: I assume you preg_match() the value in the validatePattern function.
Since we don't know what is happening there, it's hard to understand the error.
But what i can tell you is that you send a string value to the validate function, it depends what is expected of it later on.

Comment: This is function :             private static function _validatePattern($pattern, $value)
    {
        $validity = false;
        $validity = preg_match($pattern, $value);
        return $validity;
    }

Comment: Is your $requestObj object defined previously in the code?
That might return an error and prevent further execution.

just tested a local snippet and works great:
`code`
function _validatePattern($pattern, $value) { $validity = false; $validity = preg_match($pattern, $value); return $validity; }
$aa =["10.74.10.1", "10.75.10.132"];
$uu = array();
if (is_array($aa)) {
                  
    foreach ($aa as $ipValue) {
        $uu[] = (_validatePattern("/^\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}$/", ((trim($ipValue)) ?? FALSE) )) ? trim($ipValue):NULL;
    }
}
print_r($uu);
`code`

Comment: Thanks much. I was defining $requestObj for clientip two times. Now it is working fine

Comment: Great, I'm glad you got it sorted out.

Answer (score 1):

You condition :

`if (isset($json->clientip) && $json->clientip != '' && $json->clientip != NULL)`

can return `true` with an array.

better use something like this : 
`if (isset($json->clientip) && is_string($json->clientip))`

Comment: Now i am getting this error :  preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in..

Answer (score 0):

Exactly as it's telling you,

"10.74.10.1", "10.75.10.132" is an array. Explode requires a string because it creates an array based on the seperator `,`

Try a var_dump() on your $json->clientip and see what it looks like, you may have to re-work your code a bit here.

Answer (score 0):

Can I propose a possibility? I would check for both possible cases. If array execute one way, if string execute your explode.

```
if (!isset($json->clientip)) {
    // thow exception or return call
}

$requestObj->clientip = [];

if (is_array($json->clientip)) {
  array_walk($json->clientip, function($ipValue) use(&$requestObj) {
    $ipValue = trim($ipValue);
    $requestObj->clientip[] = (Utils::validatePattern(Utils::REGEXP_SECLOGS_IP, (($ipValue) ?? FALSE) )) ? $ipValue:NULL;
  });
} else if (is_string($json->clientip)) {
   // execute your explode
}
```

Also I would advice to check on Marshallers to help you parse logic in your code to tidy it up more instead of leaving it all into the same place. So your Utils::validatePattern could be a Marshaller in my opinion